# find a third vector to form a set that spans $\mathbb R^{3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, 3d, singular-values

i have two vectors that i need to combine with a third unknown vector to create a spanning set, but i can't figure out how to do this. i have written the two vectors i have below. this is from a singular value decomposition problem.

$u_1 = (\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 0)$

$u_2 = (\frac{-1}{3\sqrt{2}}, \frac{-1}{3\sqrt{2}}, \frac{-4}{3\sqrt{2}})$

i am trying to solve a problem based on an example in my e-text, but they kind of skipped over this part and i can't figure out how to get this similar result for the vectors i'm working with. i have $u_1$ and $u_2$, but i can't figure out how to get $u_3$.

[image: screenshot from text]

any advice? thank you in advance!

Comment: Note that the first two coordinates of the two basis vectors, viewed as vectors in $\mathbb R^2$, span $\mathbb R^2$. Hence, $(0,0,1)$ is an example of a vector that would complete the basis.

Comment: I'd suggest taking the cross product

Comment: If you want to follow your e-text, do exactly as it says, that is, solve the set of equations $u_1^Tx = u_2^Tx=0$

Comment: @Exodd how would i go about setting those equations up?

Comment: Is there a typographical error here?  As typed, $u_1\cdot u_3\ne0$ and $u_2\cdot u_3\ne0$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner $u_3$ in the screenshot is from a different example. i included the screenshot to illustrate why i'm stuck. i need to find a different $u_3$ for the first two vectors that i wrote down myself, but i found the explanation from the text about how to do this to be unclear.

Comment: If $x=(a,b,c)$ then $u_1^Tx=0$ means $\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}a+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}b=0$.

Comment: @qwerty:  I see.  Do you know about [cross products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product)?

Comment: so this would mean that i would use those transposes of the u vectors as rows in a matrix and then row reduce it and normalize the result to get the third vector, right?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner for some reason that concept hasn't been introduced in my class. i learned about it years ago in calculus 3 though. i will try this too.

Comment: @qwerty:  feel free to leave a comment below my answer if you'd like me to check your answer for $u_3$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $u_1$ and $u_2$ as given are unit vectors that are perpendicular to each other

(their dot product is $0$),

their vector [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) will be a unit vector perpendicular to them, which is what is sought.

Answer (score 1):

For any set of $n - k$ linearly independent vectors in an $n$-dimensional vector space, we can extend to a basis by appending some $k$ of the standard basis vectors $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ (proof: add all of them in and sift).

In this case, it's easy to see that $(0,0,1)$ is linearly independent of your set of vectors, so that one will do.